# Im trying to bind value from select2 list to model on post razor mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, .net-core, jquery-select2

I currently have an edit view for a model on a razor page, .net-core. The code below works in terms of selecting the value I pass in for the PartId on the select2 dropdown list. My issue is that when I try to post again on the form without touching the part element, the validation is complaining that its not set. I have seen it set to 0 when passed to the action on the controller which is not correct.

**Html for Part on form**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="form-label">Part</label>
    <select name="PartId" id="selectpicker1" class="form-control" data-style="btn-default">
       <option></option>
    </select>
<span asp-validation-for="PartId" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#selectpicker1').select2({
     placeholder: 'Select a part',
     data: JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model.PartsList))'),

     initSelection: function (element, callback) {
     var data= { id: @Model.PartId.ToString(), text: '@Model.PartsList.Where(x=> x.Id == Model.PartId.ToString() ).First().Text'};
     callback(data);
     }
});
```

If I reselect the same same item, it binds correctly and is sent to action on the controller. I haven't provided the action or the rest of the form as this functionality is working correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by removing:

```
 initSelection: function (element, callback) {
     var data= { id: @Model.PartId.ToString(), text: '@Model.PartsList.Where(x=> x.Id == Model.PartId.ToString() ).First().Text'};
     callback(data);
 }
```

and using the following (currently it selects option 99 but I can replace this with the PartId from the model.

```
 $('#selectpicker1').val('99');
 $('#selectpicker1').trigger('change');
```